# is there is a solution for urls issues

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I am building a web app using django and I get an error, I couldn't figure out what is the problem behind it.
I have three models( Category, SubCategory, Article) in my url I want something like that (localhost:8000/categories/Id_category/Id_subcategory)
the url (localhost:8000/categories/Id_category) worked perfectly but (localhost:8000/categories/Id_category/Id_subcategory) didn't work I get this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvfuI.png)
So here is my code that I tried to make it:

```
#views.py
def categorie(request):
    Catégorie_list=Catégorie.objects.all()
    context = {
     'Catégorie_list':Catégorie_list, 
    }
    return render(request,'articles/Category.html',context)

def souscategorie(request,categoryID): 
    SousCatégorie_list=SousCatégorie.objects.order_by('désignation').filter(Catégorie_identifiant_id=categoryID)
    name_category=Catégorie.objects.get(id=categoryID)
    articles=Article.objects.select_related('Sous_Catégorie__Catégorie_identifiant').filter(Sous_Catégorie__Catégorie_identifiant_id=categoryID)
    context = {
     'SousCatégorie_list':SousCatégorie_list,
     'name_category': name_category,
     'articles':articles 
    }
    return render(request,'articles/SubCategory.html',context)



def articl(request,categoryID,articleID):
    return render(request,'articles/article.html')


#articles/urls.py

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.categorie, name='Category'),
    path('<int:categoryID>/',views.souscategorie, name='SubCategory'),
    path('<int:categoryID>/<int:articleID>/',views.articl, name='article'),
    path('search',views.search, name='search'), 
]
#my template Category.html
{% if Catégorie_list %}
                    {% for category in Catégorie_list %}
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
                            <div class="card listing-preview">
                                <a href="{% url 'SubCategory' category.id %}">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ category.photo_main.url }}" alt="{{ category.désignation }}"> </a>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="listing-heading text-center">
                                        <a href="{% url 'SubCategory' category.id %}" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <h4 class="text-primary" >{{ category.désignation }}</h4>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="listing-heading text-center">
                                        <a class="text-primary" >{{ category.Description }}</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <a href="{% url 'SubCategory' category.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Voir la catégorie</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                {% else %}
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>Aucune catégorie disponible</p>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}

#my template Subcategory.html
<div class="row">
    {% if articles %}
        {% for article in articles %}
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                <div class="card h-100">
                        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ article.photo_main.url }}"  alt=""></a>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">
                                <a href="{% url 'article' name_category.id article.id  %}">{{ article.désignation }}</a>
                            </h4>
                            <h5>{{ article.Sous_Catégorie }}</h5>
                              <p class="card-text">{{ article.Description }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                           <h6 class="text-muted">Ajouter au panier</h6>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <a class="list-group-item"> Aucune sous catégorie disponible</a>
    {% endif %}

</div>
```

Comment: The error is in your `articl` function.

Comment: hence in the `articles/article.html` template, not in the subcategories template.

Comment: post the code from where you are requesting for this url

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry I don't understand your point

Comment: @PankajSharma I added the category's template

Comment: add `articles/article.html` template

Comment: the article template is still a markup

Comment: @PankajSharma I edited the article template and it is worked thanks sur